# xmlpatterns: could not find a Qt installation of ''

Tags: qt5

As part of compiling some external packages like paraview from their sources, I installed the following Qt related packages using aptitude:

```
sudo apt install libqt5x11extras5-dev libqt5help5 qttools5-dev qtxmlpatterns5-dev-tools libqt5svg5-dev cmake-qt-gui qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev qtbase5-dev-tools qt5-style-plugins
```

However, the compilation of paraview runs into issues with `xmlpatterns`. Upon having a closer look, it seems like the aptitude installation of `xmlpatterns` gives this error:

```
xmlpatterns: could not find a Qt installation of ''
```

which is the same error paraview compilation runs into. Can someone please clarify/correct what went wrong with aptitude packages?

P.S. I am using Ubuntu 22.04

Edit: Just now, I noticed that `/usr/bin/xmlpatterns` points to `/usr/bin/qtchooser`, which seems odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're just missing `libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev`.

```
sudo apt install libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev
```

Comment: I installed this package, still have the same error. Also, `xmlpatterns` still points to `qtchooser` as mentioned before.

Comment: Do you have `qt5-default` installed? It being missing can cause that error too.

Comment: `qt5-default` is not available on Ubuntu 22.04. I tried to add the old repositories of Ubuntu 20.04 (focal-security), but `apt` couldn't install it because of version conflicts in dependencies

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Stab in the dark, but how about `qtbase5-private-dev`? Do you have that too?

Comment: No, I don't have that installed. However, I solved my problem by finding another `xmlpatterns` binary and then link it to the one in path. i.e. by applying `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/qt5/bin/xmlpatterns /usr/bin/xmlpatterns`

Comment: Not sure if this is the right way to do things, but paraview compilation worked flawlessly